# React useState gets previous value after history.push

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to change URL when `<RadioGroup onChange={handleCategoryChange}/>` event fired:

```
const history = useHistory();
const { categoryId } = props;
const [category, setCategory] = useState(categoryId);

const handleCategoryChange = event => {
    history.push(`/books/${event.target.value}`)
};
```

Url will change according to `categoryId` parameter.

But when the page re-renders with new `categoryId` it still gets the previous value while I am expecting it to set the new `categoryId`

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(categoryId);
```

Comment: You have to use `useEffect` to get the new props. It's somehow equivalent to `componentWillReceiveProps` (if you are familiar with it).

Comment: yes. useEffect also works.thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the new value:

```
const history = useHistory();
const { categoryId } = props;
const [category, setCategory] = useState(categoryId);

const handleCategoryChange = event => {
    setCategory(event.target.value);
    history.push(`/books/${event.target.value}`)
};
```

Comment: it worked thank you. I had thought it would set the props value with useState each time it renders.